# JS recursive code throwing maximum call stack size error

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I know this might be basic and simple but since I am self-learning, so I wanted to know what was wrong and I thought this is the best place to learn from.

I am trying to write a recursive code that returns true or false. The condition to check is if the set of words can make the given target word.

The error I keet getting is :

```
 if (targetString.indexOf(dictionary[i]) == 0) {
                     ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.indexOf (<anonymous>)
```

I am pretty sure that the problem with code is in a way I am returning because I always find it confusing.

my code is:

```js
let targetString = "furniture";
let dictionary = ["fur", "ure", "nit"];
const tableData = {};

const canConstructRecursive = (targetString, dictionary) => {
  if (targetString == "") {
    return true
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    if (targetString.indexOf(dictionary[i]) == 0) {
      shorterTargetString = targetString.slice(0, dictionary[i].length);
      return canConstructRecursive(shorterTargetString, dictionary);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(canConstructRecursive(targetString, dictionary));
```

I am learning recursion and from time to time I feel I don't understand the logic of return to next/previous recursive call.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with what I am doing wrong and change my way of thinking.

My way of thinking is that:

the base case is returned if it is reached at that stage otherwise loop go through all the option and the inner node or upper stack need to return value to lower stack so I am doing return canConstructRecursive() inside for. If even in all options which is all iteration of for loop, it is not returned, there is return false at the end.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that although your variable is named `shorterTargetString`, it is not guaranteed to be really shorter. If `i` is the index of the shortest word in `dictionary`, then there is no way your string will ever get shorter by recursing with it.

The mistake is that the slice should not *start* at 0, but *after* the part that was matched, so remove the first argument from the `slice` call.

This will solve the stack overflow error.

Secondly, if the recursive call returns `false` you should not give up, but keep trying with the next word. So only `return` out of the loop when you got `true` from recursion:

```js
let targetString = "furniture";
let dictionary = ["fur", "ure", "nit"];
const tableData = {};

const canConstructRecursive = (targetString, dictionary) => {
  if (targetString == "") {
    return true
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    if (targetString.indexOf(dictionary[i]) == 0) {
      shorterTargetString = targetString.slice(dictionary[i].length);
      if (canConstructRecursive(shorterTargetString, dictionary)) {
         return true;
      };
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(canConstructRecursive(targetString, dictionary));
```

### More on the second fix.

Your code will unconditionally return the value of the recursive call, even when it is `false`. This is not good: in case the recursive call returns `false`, the caller should continue with its `for` loop to try alternatives.

Let's for instance add a word to your example dictionary: you'll agree that *adding* a dictionary word should not change the outcome for the input "furniture". So here it is:

```
["furn", "fur", "ure", "nit"]
```

But surprise: your code now returns `false` for "furniture"! This is because "furn" mathes, but the recursive call with "iture" as first argument does not find further matches, so it returns `false`, and now the caller *also* returns `false`. This is wrong. It should give up on "furn", but not on the whole exercise. It should have continued and tried with "fur". This is why the exit out of the `for` loop should only happen upon *success*, not upon *failure*. Failure can only be confirmed when *all* dictionary words have been tried, so the `for` loop must continue for as long as there is no recursive success.

Comment: thank you for your response yes, that slice was a big blunder but still I am not able to understand the return logic inside the if condition check

Comment: Once you have hit the base case, you'll want to exit with `true` out of all levels of recursion, right? So that is why every recursive call must bubble up that same `true` return without doing anything else. It must be a quick exit. If however you hit another (implicit) base case -- i.e. the one where none of the dictionary words matches with `indexOf` -- and the function returns `false`, then you **don't** want that quick exit. You'll want to look at alternatives, so the caller should not exit their loop.

Comment: I am curious to ask that the code is running with old code but with the change in slice indexes you corrected, can I ask why?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying here. Are you asking why the *second* correction is really necessary?

Comment: I meant to ask this is working: https://jsfiddle.net/5d34cvsa/1/ I thought if I could know why this is working without returning as you said, I can understand what you are saying in case of return usage in recursion.

Comment: Change the input to `["furn", "fur", "ure", "nit"]`, and see the difference in output.

Comment: yes, because like you said, I think even with return with the function I see that it goes to check with every possible word in dictionary. I just can't see that if the function returns false it doesn't go to check any other dictionary words.

Comment: Because you `return ` the recursive call unconditionally, also when it is `false`. That `return` will abort the `for` loop it is in. Just use a debugger and step through the code with the extended example I gave. I really cannot explain more. It's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

User trincot already explained what was wrong with your code.  Here, I just want to point out that your structure, which is something like `for (...) {if (...) { if (...) {return true} } } return false`, might be better handled with `Array.prototype.some` and an `&&` statement.  Combining this with the fact that `t .indexOf (s) == 0` might more clearly be expressed as `t .startsWith (s)`, and sprinkling in a conditional statement instead of an `if` statement, we can arrive at what I think is a more elegant formulation:

```js
const canConstruct = (t = '', ss = []) => 
  t == ''
    ? true
    : ss .some ((s) => t .startsWith (s) && canConstruct (t .slice (s .length), ss))

console .log (canConstruct ('furniture', ['fur', 'ure', 'nit'])) //=> true
console .log (canConstruct ('furniture', ['furn', 'fur', 'ure', 'nit'])) //=> true
console .log (canConstruct ('banana', ['b', 'ana'])) //=> false
console .log (canConstruct ('banana', ['ba', 'na'])) //=> true
```